# Cut NSString from space to end

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, cut

I have NSString:

> sessid=os3vainreuru2hank3; __ubic1=MzcxMzjMDYuNjk0NDA1Mzc%3D;
>   auto_login=123; sid=kep8efpo7; last_user=123;

I need get just:

> __ubic1=MzcxMzjMDYuNjk0NDA1Mzc%3D; auto_login=123;
>   interpals_sessid=kep8efpo7; last_user=123;

But count of characters past sessid may vary

Thanks! Sorry for simple question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.-

```
NSRange range = [yourString rangeOfString:@" "];
if (NSNotFound != range.location) {
    yourString = [yourString substringFromIndex:(range.location + 1)];
}
```

Basically, you get the index for the first `space` character, and then the substring from that index to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least one character you can search for. Looks like that double underscore will work.

```
NSRange stringStart = [originalString rangeOfString:@"__"];
NSString *extractedString = [originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(stringStart.location, originalString.length - stringStart.location)];
```

That should get you what you need!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[originalString componentsSeperatedByString:@";"] mutableCopy];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
NSString* newString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
```

I assume you mistyped interpals_sessid with sid